# How to handle space in filename in bash script?

Tags: bash

I want to automate rsyncing, and tried the following code:

```
TARGET="/media/USB\ DISK/Backup/"
rsync -av --delete ~/Data ${TARGET}
```

but the execution results in the following error:

```
rsync: link_stat "/media/USB\" failed: No such file or directory (2)
rsync: mkdir "/home/DISK/BACKUP" failed: No such file or directory (2)
```

because of the 'space' in the target filename. However, when I `echo` the command I can use that to run on the shell directly.

How to do it correctly (which brackets, with backslash or without?) and why?

Comment: Does not work, still get the `mkdir` error. I suggest to post a complete working example.

Comment: To eliminate the `mkdir` error, double quote `${TARGET}` in the rsync command. Otherwise, `bash` expands it into two arguments with the result that `rsync` will try to copy files from ~/Data and from /media/USB into DISK/Backup/.

Answer (score 12):

There are two possibilities:

```
TARGET="/media/USB DISK/Backup/"
rsync -av --delete ~/Data "${TARGET}"
```

or

```
TARGET=/media/USB\ DISK/Backup/
rsync -av --delete ~/Data "${TARGET}"
```

The first one preserves the space by quoting the whole string.  The second one preserves the space by escaping it with a backslash.  Also, the argument to the `rsync` command needs to be quoted.

When the string is both double-quoted and the space is preceded by a backslash, as in `TARGET="a\ b"`, the result is that `TARGET` contains a literal backslash which is probably not what you wanted.  For more details, see the section entitled "Quoting" in `man bash`.

Answer (score 0):

You should **use quotes** around your string. String should be **quoted both at declaration and when used/called**.

### Why use quotes ?

#### Metacharacters [[1]](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/Quotes#Preserve_unescaped_metacharacters)

> The first function of quoting is to permit words to **contain these
>   metacharacters**.

#### Word splitting and globbing [[2]](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/Quotes#Prevent_field_splitting_and_ignore_glob_pattern_characters)

> The second purpose of quoting is to **prevent [word splitting](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/WordSplitting) and
>   globbing**.

### Type of quotes

For details read the [*Types of quoting* section](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/Quotes#Types_of_quoting).

#### Simple quotes (POSIX)

> Everything between single quotes is **literal** and expands to a single
>   word

#### Double quotes (POSIX)

> permit the shell to **parse their contents** for those types of expansions
>   that are prefixed with a `$` sign - parameter expansions, arithmetic
>   expansions and command substitutions, while treating all other content
>   as literal […]

#### Bash quoting `$'…'` and `$"…"`

Those are non-POSIX (supported by Bash, Ksh93, etc.):

- `$'…'` : allow backslash-escaped sequence to be used/expanded (`\n`, `\t`, etc.) ;
- `$"…"` : for translation

### References

- http://mywiki.wooledge.org/Quotes ;
- http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/quoting.

Answer (score 0):

Try this. I think the curly braces (parameter expansion) messed it up.

```
TARGET="/media/USB DISK/Backup/"
rsync -av --delete ~/Data "$TARGET"
```