# Variables and Arithmetic Expressions C language

Tags: c

Hello I'm new to C and am using a book called *The C programming language by Brian W.Kernighan 2nd Edition*.

In chapter 1.2 there's a practice on how to use the formula `Celsius = (5/9)(Fahrenheit-32)` to print a table with Fahrenheit temperatures and celsius equivalent.

I am unable to figure what the error message meant.
Is there a problem with my code?
Or is it the compiler problem? Since I put it in the same folder as my other program.
I'm using Visual studio btw and I don't know how to save the new program in a new folder.
Everytime I tries to make a new folder and save it there they said path not found. Thus, me making programs in the same folder

The code that I write as follows:

```
#include <stdio.h>

/* print Fahrenheit-Celsius table
for fahr = 0, 20, ...,300 */
main()
{
    int fahr, celsius;
    int lower, upper, step;
    lower = 0;   /* lower limit of temperature table */
    upper = 300; /* upper limit */
    step = 20;   /* step size */

    fahr = lower;
    while (fahr <= upper) {
        celsius = 5 * (fahr - 32) / 9;
        printf("%d\t%d\n", fahr, celsius);
        fahr = fahr + step
    }
}
```

The output is as follows
https://i.stack.imgur.com/RkANS.png

Comment: To make for a better question, post the output here as text.

Comment: You're missing a semicolon in line `fahr =fahr + step`.

Comment: Thank you I added the semicolon but it still says error. I tried copying but the visual studio won't let me copy the output

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to handle space in filename in bash script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20480070/how-to-handle-space-in-filename-in-bash-script)

Comment: I'm really new to C programming @Siguza some of the error messages does resemble my error message however I don't understand the solution

Comment: @JeremyAlvin It has nothing to do with C. It's just your shell splitting arguments at spaces.

Comment: regarding: `main()`  There are only two valid signatures for the `main()` function.  They are: `int main( void )` and `int main( int argc, char *argv[] )`  Some non-compliant compilers  will allow other signatures for `main()` however, do not use other signatures.

Comment: regarding: `fahr = fahr + step`  This statement is missing the required trailing semicolon `;`  I.E. `fahr = fahr + step;`

Comment: regarding: `celsius = 5 * (fahr - 32) / 9;`  The result is a floating point value, not an integer.  So the result is any fractional part of the result is truncated/lost

Answer (score 3):

The file name cannot contain spaces.

Try renaming the file from `Variable and Artithmetic.c` to `Variable_and_Arithmetic.c`

Comment: I did and it helped, but the error message stays the same. Still Thank you

Comment: The output file can’t have spaces in the name either - use `gcc -o  variable_and_arithmetic variable_and_arithmetic.c`.

Comment: @JohnBode: the command on Jeremy's terminal is likely generated by the IDE. Just renaming the source file should suffice as the name of the source file will be used for the executable one too.

Answer (score 2):

compiler is thinking that 'variable', 'and', 'arithmetic' are three different arguments. Change filename into something that does not contain any spaces.